# regular expression using lookahead negative assertion

Tags: php, regex, assertion, regex-lookarounds

Using php I would like to detect something in a string depending on whether the part immediately after the matched part does not contain certain characters. I think I may need to use a lookahead negative assertion but it is not working as I would expect so not sure. So for example:

```
$string = 'test somerandomURL><b>apple</b> peach orange';
```

I want an expression that will detect everything up to the first > so long as `<b>apple</b>` does not immediately follow the first >

I tried

```
if(preg_match("/test(.*)>(?!<b>apple<\/b>)(.*)/i",$string)){
echo 'true since <b>apple</b> does not follow > in string';
}else{
echo 'false since <b>apple</b> follows > in string';
}
```

When the string contains `<b>apple</b>` after the > it returns false as I expect and need but when I change the string to have `<b>peach</b>` after the > instead of `<b>apple</b>` it still returns false and I need it to return true. Without the bold tags it seems to work as I would expect. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The first `.*` already matches most of the input string (until the closing `</b>`s `>` probably), making your assertion somewhat superfluous. Try `[^>]*` instead. --(And before someone posts the redundant-and-only-kept-for-historical-reasons joke link, yes, there are [simpler APIs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for processing text with interspersed html.)

Comment: Try this: `(?=test.*?><b>(?!apple)[^<]+)[^>]+`

Comment: what wouldn't the first `.*` stop at the first `> and how do I make it do so?

Comment: @Enissay, if you think you have a solution, post it as an answer, not as a comment.  But don't post that one; `(?=test.*?><b>` is never going to succeed because requires the next four characters to be both `test` and `<b>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a few things wrong, including not turning on error reporting because you have mismatched `()`'s and an `/` that needs escaping.

The first problem is that .* is greedy. So in your string it will match: `test somerandomURL><b>apple</b>`

Usually the solution to that is to make it lazy with `.*?` but because of the negative lookahead, laziness will still make it match up to a further `>` when apple is found.

The solution is a negated character class. `[^>]*` will match any char except `>`

```
/test([^>]*)>(?!<b>apple<\/b>)(.*)/i
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed up the errors and your expression got me the results I wanted.